# Plotting a trend graph in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot

I have the following data in a DataFrame:

```
+----------------------+--------------+-------------------+
| Physician Profile Id | Program Year | Value Of Interest |
+----------------------+--------------+-------------------+
| 1004777              |     2013     |    83434288.00    |
| 1004777              |     2014     |    89237990.00    |
| 1004777              |     2015     |    96321258.00    |
| 1004777              |     2016     |    186993309.00   |
| 1004777              |     2017     |    205274459.00   |
| 1315076              |     2013     |    127454475.84   |
| 1315076              |     2014     |    156388338.20   |
| 1315076              |     2015     |    199733425.11   |
| 1315076              |     2016     |    242766959.37   |
+----------------------+--------------+-------------------+
```

I want to plot a trend graph with the Program year on the x-axis and Value of Interest on the y-axis and different lines for each Physician Profile ID. What is the best way to get this done?

Comment: Plotly has a example of exactly this: https://plot.ly/python/linear-fits/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a few things and was able to implement it:

```
years = df["Program_Year"].unique()

PhysicianIds = sorted(df["Physician_Profile_ID"].unique())

pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

for ID in PhysicianIds:
    df_filter = df[df["Physician_Profile_ID"] == ID]
    for year in years:
        found = False
        for index, row in df_filter.iterrows():
            if row["Program_Year"] == year:
                found = True
                break
            else:
                found = False
        if not found:
            df_filter.loc[index+1] = [ID, year, 0]
    VoI = list(df_filter["Value_of_Interest"])
    sns.lineplot(x=years, y=VoI, label=ID, linestyle='-')

plt.ylabel("Value of Interest (in 100,000,000)")
plt.xlabel("Year")
plt.title("Top 10 Physicians")
plt.legend(title="Physician Profile ID")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Two routes I'd consider going with this:

- Basic, fast, easy: [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/), which would look something like this:

  - install it, like `pip install matplotlib`
  - use it, like `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and [this cheatsheet](https://www.datacamp.com/community/blog/python-matplotlib-cheat-sheet)
- Graphically compelling and you can drop your pandas dataframe right into it: [Bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/)

I hope that helps you get started!